# Given, $f(x+y) =xf(x) +2f(y)-x-y$. If $f(2019)=\frac{a}{b}$, then $a+b=?$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> **Question:**
>   $\text{Given, } f(x+y) =xf(x) +2f(y)-x-y\text{. If } f(2019)=\frac{a}{b}, \text{then } a+b\text{ = ?} $

I started solving by replacing $y\to-x$, which yields
$$f(0) = xf(x) +2f(-x)$$
then, replace $x\to-x$
$$f(0)=-xf(-x)+2f(x)$$
on solving, I get,
$$(x+2)f(0)=(x^2+4)f(x)$$

But, I'm stuck here. How to move on?

Comment: Let $x=0$. You will find that $f(0)=2f(0)$, thus $f(0)=0$

Comment: if you put $x=y=0$, you get $f(0) = 0$

Comment: So that one solution is $f(x) = 0$, but that's probably not the only solution

Comment: Something feels weird. Let $x=1,y=0$. We find that $f(1)=f(1)-1$ which has no solutions...

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, I had tried it, but that makes $f(x) =0$, which ruins the question. Also, is it legal to make $x=y=0$ to find $f(c) $?

Comment: Are x and y positive integers? If so, we can't have f(0).

Comment: There are no such $f$?

Comment: Are you sure the sum has been copied properly? I remember seeing pretty much the same problem before but it was slightly different.

Comment: @Rahul Verma do you have a domain given? Is it possible that your source may contain a typo, or that you may have made one?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, I was asking if I can replace x and y with constants, to find f(0)?

Comment: @Rahul Verma That's exactly why I was asking for the domain. $x=y=0$ is legal if $0$ is in the domain. Else, illegal. And could you please specify how you would replace $x,y$ with constants and proceed?

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar, I couldn't be sure of the source. But, one of the regular users on a discussion app had asked this and no typo for sure.

Comment: Can you ask for the source?

Comment: Also, $f(x)=0$ is true subject to the condition that $x+y=0$. Via substitution in the original equation.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, Okay I'll ask for source and domain of $f$ and I'll notify you as it might take a long time. Goodbye.

Comment: If $f$ exists (I don't think it does), then either $x$ and $y$ live in a very weird domain or the symbols as written don't represent their common meanings.

Answer (score 1):

If $x=0$ we get $f(y)=y$ for all $y$. Pluging this in to starting equation we get $$x+y=x^2+2y-x-y$$

which should be valid for all $x,y$. Since $x^2=2x$ ony for $x=2$ and $x=0$ this FE has no solution unlesss $f$ is defined on the set $\{0,2\}$.